# where are the tap featues of the Airpods on the Airpod Pros?

Tags: airpods

I recently got some Airpod Pro earphones. I'm accustomed to being able to tap my left Airpod to advance to the next track and my right Airpod to toggle pause/play

I can't seem to find similar features on the Airpod Pros. First there appears to be no tap options only squeeze and second the squeeze options are only noise settings and Siri. Further, squeeze  is not nearly as convenient as tap since I can tap my AirPods with my hands full but can’t squeeze.

Is there some way to enable the tap options on AirPods Pros or are these really a downgrade from the functionality of the standard AirPods?

Answer (score 5):

Tap on AirPods is replaced with a press on the stem (squeeze) on AirPods Pro.

On either AirPods Pro stem:

- Single press for play/pause
- Double press to skip media (next song, etc)
- Triple press to play from start, or if at start, previous media (last song, etc)
- Hold stem for the custom action in Settings, i.e. switch listening mode or start Siri.

Answer (score 1):

**There are no “tap” functions on the AirPods Pro.**

That is a function of the 1st and 2nd generation AirPods. The AirPods Pro uses a new force sensor that you press (what you call squeeze) to activate its functions.

You can get full details from the Apple Support document [Connect and Use Your AirPods and AirPods Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207010)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that you find the new AirPods pro gestures less convenient than tapping, especially with your hands full.

One feature that resolved this really well (which was available on AirPods v2 as well) is the always-on Siri. This provides full hands free control!

I also think you’ll learn to enjoy the added functionality that the new gestures bring. As mentioned in another answer, you can now do multiple actions on either AirPod Pro - whereas before you were limited to one.